# In place modification of larger than memory Dask array

Tags: python, arrays, dask

I have a dask array, X, that is approx. 3500 by 700000. Each row has missing values that I need to impute according to the mean of that row.

Currently this array is stored as a dask array, and I have a delayed function that can perform the imputation. When I use the compute method however, the memory fills up as it seems to be attempting to leave me with a numpy array.

Is there a way I can apply this imputation on the array in place such that I end up with the imputed array as an out of memory dask array?

Comment: Please can you show the code you are currently using, the minimum to demonstrate the effect.

Answer (score 1):

WHen you apply a delayed function onto a dask array it will have to convert your array into a single numpy array.  See http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed-best-practices.html#don-t-call-dask-delayed-on-other-dask-collections

You might want to consider chunking your array so that rows are in single chunks and then using `map_blocks`.